# NSolve doesn't find all solutions in a range

Tags: equation-solving

In `13.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)` if I write:

```
f[x_] := Cos[x] - 0.9999977306829412 + 0.49986470623284673 x^2 - 0.04072419545671301 x^4

sol = NSolve[{f[x] == 0, -π/4 < x < π/4}];

Plot[f[x], {x, -π/4, π/4}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"},
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol]}]
```

I get:

[image]

where it's clear that `NSolve` doesn't find two solutions. How can I solve it?

Comment: While I wait for other answers, I'll add that `TrigToExp[f[x]]` works.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 keeps the incorrect solutions for all answers! An old bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `Reals`.

```
f[x_] := 
  Cos[x] - 0.9999977306829412 + 0.49986470623284673 x^2 - 
   0.04072419545671301 x^4;
sol = NSolve[f[x] == 0, Reals];
Plot[f[x], {x, -π/4, π/4}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Solving between -Pi and Pi/2 gives the desired result

```
sol = NSolve[{f[x] == 0, -Pi < x < Pi/2}];

Plot[f[x], {x, -\[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol]}]
```

[image]